# Выводить только до "," сейчас выводит 2 слова через кому Java

Tags: java

В этом поле BRANCH_ADDRESS нужно выводить только  до "," сейчас BRANCH_ADDRESS выводит два слова через кому нужно только первое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Текстовую информацию нужно добавить в вопрос текстом вместо скриншота.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `String[] split(String regex)` возвращает массив строк, разбитых по регулярному выражению.
Если вам необходимо получать всё до первой запятой, ипользуйте

```
getAdress().split(",")[0];
```